# How to generate a SQL Server compatible database with Entity Framework (code first)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I was following this tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-awesome-guide-on-how-to-build-restful-apis-with-asp-net-core-87b818123e28/ and I got everything right and working but this example API is using the `InMemoryDatabase` option. I want to use a SQL Server database with it (I'm using the code first approach).

I have tried to create a database with no tables in SQL Server Management Studio and use a connection string with the following code in my `Startup` class, and it is working and saving data to the database but it does not appear in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddDbContext<GameCollectionDbContext>(options =>
             {
                  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBGAMESCOLLECTION"));
                  // options.UseInMemoryDatabase("GAME_COLLECTION_DB");
             });

    services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ICollectionsRepository, CollectionsRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IGamesRepository, GamesRepository>();

    services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();
    services.AddScoped<ICollectionsService, CollectionsService>();
    services.AddScoped<IGamesService, GamesService>();

    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

My `appsettings.json` looks like this

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "DBGAMESCOLLECTION": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=GAMES_COLLECTION_DB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
 }
```

All I want is to make Entity Framework create the database in my local machine based on the models I declared and the resulting database to be available in SQL Server for making queries and stored procedures.

(UPDATE)

I guess I should be clearer. I created my REST API with a code first approach because I expected to create models and based on that get a database file or script. It is the first time I implemented EF all by myself so at first I used the InMemoryDatabase option for my context but I knew that was only for testing purposes. After the API worked as expected I moved on to use a real database for persistance. So I added this to my Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddDbContext<GameCollectionDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBGAMESCOLLECTION"));
            //options.UseInMemoryDatabase("GAME_COLLECTION_DB");

        });
}
```

And my appsettings.json ended like this.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBGAMESCOLLECTION": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=GAMES_COLLECTION_DB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Up to that point the database worked and data was being saved after stopping the context but I was wondering where my database was created because in SSMS it didn't show up in my machine. I finally found that because of the connections string I was using another instance of sqlexpress and when I connected to the '(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB' engine in SSMS server name it was there.

So I now got an sql server database and a connection string to it so I can work in the mean while. My question then is, How is this configuration gonna work in real life? the connection string I wrote in appsettings.json is the place where the database is going to be created? so if I put a server ip it will be there?

Comment: So, the only problem is that the localdb database does not show up in SSMS?

Comment: sort of, I'm more familiar managing the databases there. also I want to see how the information is being stored.

Comment: it may seem weird but I've seen projects like that but I don't know if it is possible only when using the database first approach. I used to implement regular asp mvc without entity framework

Comment: Entity Framework is using the database specified in the connection string. Other than that and no matter what approach you use it is still just a plain SQL Server Express LocalDB database. Obviously, you already have access to the database from SSMS (since you've had it created in SSMS). Also, you've said that data are being saved to the database. So, by refreshing the tables in SSMS you should be able to see the data. I am not sure what your question is exactly...

Comment: I said it is working and saving data because when I restart the api in visual studio the data I inserted before shows up but I dont have access from ssms. I created a database in ssms with same name as the one in the connection string but it has no tables or data. I also tried attaching it from the mdf files in the project folder but they won't open either

Comment: The thing I need is to either make EF create a database in ssms or create one with a script based on my models and make the API use that. (I don't want to use databse first). I also need it to be on ssms for other application to have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...
In your `appsettings.json` ('String' not 'Strings'):

```
"ConnectionString": {
    "DBGAMESCOLLECTION": "..."
  }
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:DBGAMESCOLLECTION"]));
```

And you have to add [Code-First Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/). Migrations automate the creation of database based on your Models. Something like:

```
PM> Add-Migration *Some_Description*

PM> update-database
```

Comment: tried that but got an error when running the command 'Unable to create an object of type 'GameCollectionDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<GameCollectionDbContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.'.   after searching it says that I should implement that interface where my context class is but all the code I found doesn't look like mine.

Comment: In my example did you replace `ApplicationContext` with your `ApplicationContext`? Forgot to change that.

Comment: this is my conext class:  https://github.com/danielfernandezag/net-core-api-example/blob/master/GameCollectionAPI/Persistence/Contexts/GameCollectionDbContext.cs

Comment: yes, I changed it. this is my startup class: https://github.com/danielfernandezag/net-core-api-example/blob/master/GameCollectionAPI/Startup.cs

Comment: Do you have more than one DbContext?

Comment: only one called 'GameCollectionDbContext' with 3 tables or models. I've just pushed my changes so you might've seen the older version without the things you told me to try.

Comment: Seems fine, but it's hard to get a good review without running the project. Can you try to remove your dummy data (remove `OnModelCreating`) and see how that goes.

Comment: I removed the dummy data but is weird, everywhere it says that I should user enable migrations first, but PM says it is deprecated I should user add-migration and then the name, any way it still throws the same error. Should I remove the whole method? thing is I finally found my database in localDb but I'm not really sure what those commands actually do.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-an-asp-net-core-application-with-web-api-and-code-first-development/), it's one I recommend a lot. Also, for the connection string, you can try `localhost` or just `.`, instead of `(localdb)`.

Comment: Yes, kind of, I wanted to decouple the database but I was finally able to use ssms with it and make sp. The connection string worked for my other app. I'll work like this meanwhile and I'll figure it out when deploying.